# Two if statements?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Can you put an **if** statement inside of another **if** statement

```
if (statement one) {
    if (another one) {
        // do whatever
    } else {

    }
}
```

^^^ Like that idea.

Is there any way for it to work?

Comment: If you get your braces right (one is missing), yes. You could also just try it to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, this technique is called nested if statements.

Comment: yes you can; just remember that if statement 'one' is false, you never get to evaluate statement 'another' (nor its else counterpart) - this may or may not be what you intended to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but you can also use AND operator :

```
if(true && true){}
else{}
//Will go in the if

if(true && false){}
else{}
//Will go in the else
```

---

If you want multiple if :

```
if(true){
    if(true){}
}else{
    if(true){
    }else if(true){
    }
}
```

---

Note that if you do a nested if :

```
if(true){
    if(false){}
}else{
}
```

If the second condition is false, the else statement will not be proc.

Play with this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dBwU3/

Just change the value in the `if` to `false` or `true` to see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can nest `if` statements in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect the else to be executed when statement one is false or when statement one and another one is false?  If so then you should write
if (statement one && another one)  {
do whatever
} else {
}

As it coded in your question the else will get executed if statement one is false (regardless of the truth of another one.